# Read filenames and loop thru to get top line from each file to create XML

Tags: xml, batch-file

I have a folder full of text files for example

1. test.txt
2. test_1.txt

each one has one URL like this
https://ia600407.us.archive.org/34/items/zfl6_512kb.mp4

i want to get all file names of the .txt files then get the URL from each text file, give it a ID and quality as well so final would look like this

```
<channel ID='1' name='test' url='https://ia600407.us.archive.org/34/items/zfl6_512kb.mp4' quality='best' />
<channel ID='2' name='test 1' url='https://ia600407.us.archive.org/34/items/zfwrr_512kb.mp4' quality='best' />
```

Notice how the second one has no underscore for name, i need to add so it takes out underscore and adds a space in the for Loop as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir\t w o"
PUSHD "%sourcedir%"
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=[]" %%a IN ('dir /b /a-d "*.txt"^|find /n /v "" ') DO (
 SET "name=%%b"
 SET "name=!name:_= !"
 FOR /f "delims=" %%u IN ("%%b") DO (
  ECHO(^<channel ID='%%a' name='!name!' url='%%u' quality='best' /^>
 )
)

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

---

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir\t w o"
PUSHD "%sourcedir%"
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=[]" %%a IN ('dir /b /a-d "*.txt"^|find /n /v "" ') DO (
 SET "name=%%b"
 SET "name=!name:_= !"
 FOR /f "delims=" %%u IN ('type "%%b"') DO (
  >>newfile.xyz ECHO(^<channel ID='%%a' name='!name!' url='%%u' quality='best' /^>
 )
)

TYPE newfile.xyz

POPD

GOTO :EOF
```

Edit - note that `newfile.xyz` is created in `sourcedir`. If you use an explicit drive/path in the redirector string, that explicit drive/path will override the default.

Added `popd` for completeness.

Note that `for  %%u` now works on `type %%b`; previously working on the fileNAME, not content.

Comment: I forgot to say for the "name"  take off extension of .txt

The one issue i am having is it is not showing url but Name again

Comment: also i am having no luck creating the xml file where do i put the echo to write to xml ... But getting close!

Comment: To remove the `.txt` extension, use `SET "name=%%~nb"` in place of `SET "name=%%b"`. You need to specify what the contents are of the files you are processing. What does 'not url but Name' mean precisely? To redirect to a new file, use `>>newfile.xyz ECHO(^<channel...`

Comment: well each txt file has one line in it and it is a URL like this:
https://ia600407.us.archive.org/34/items/zfl6_512kb.mp4

That is where the "url=" is supposed to be "url=https://ia600407.us.archive.org/34/items/zfl6_512kb.mp4"  

where you have url='%%u' above ^

i tried placing ">>newfile.xyz ECHO(^<channel..."   an d replaced with ">>newfile.txt ECHO(^<channel..."  and it did not create a new .txt file with info that was echoed...